# Wordpress password protected uploads folder

Tags: wordpress, file, nginx, passwords, password-protection

I needs to disable direct access of my uploaded PDF files

I used [Password Protected Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/) for website , But unable to protect my pdf files

I also tried with nginx

Answer (score 0):

Plugin sometimes not works well with the documents.

So, If you want the password-protected PDF then make the PDF security with a password and after upload it in the upload folder. So it will be not accessed without the password of PDF.